# How can I use operator<< for feeding an file object to my class using <<?

Tags: c++, c++14

most of the time people overload this by making it a `friend` when they want to feed their class to an `ostream` object like `cout` for example. However for me this is not the case. I need an overload of `operator<<` that can let me do something like this:

```
std::fstream fileobj(".\example.file", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
AraHaan::hexstream hexstrm;
hexstrm << fileobj; //<--  itterates through the file object and hex arrays the data in it.
```

The issue is I am not sure how I could do this. The current Class code for `hexstream` is as follows:

```
#ifndef HEXSTREAM_DEFINED
#define HEXSTREAM_DEFINED
#include "basic_hexstream"

namespace AraHaan {
    class hexstream: public AraHaan::basic_hexstream {
    };
}

#endif
```

and `basic_hexstream`:

```
#ifndef BASIC_HEXSTREAM_DEFINED
#define BASIC_HEXSTREAM_DEFINED
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace AraHaan {
    class basic_hexstream {
    private:
        std::stringstream base_hexstream;
        bool data_cleared;
        bool append0x, writehexseparater;
    public:
        void AddCharacter(int character) {
            data_cleared = false;
            if (append0x) {
                if (writehexseparater) {
                    base_hexstream << "0x" << std::uppercase << std::setfill('0') <<
                        std::setw(2) << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned short>(character) << ", ";
                } else {
                    base_hexstream << "0x" << std::uppercase << std::setfill('0') <<
                        std::setw(2) << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned short>(character);
            }
            } else {
                if (writehexseparater) {
                    base_hexstream << std::uppercase << std::setfill('0') <<
                        std::setw(2) << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned short>(character) << ", ";
                } else {
                    base_hexstream << std::uppercase << std::setfill('0') <<
                        std::setw(2) << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned short>(character);
                }
            }
        }
        void setoptions(bool append_0x, bool writehexseparator) {
            append0x = append_0x;
            writehexseparater = writehexseparator;
        }
        const std::string str() {
            return base_hexstream.str();
        }
        void clear() {
            data_cleared = true;
            base_hexstream.clear();
            base_hexstream.str("");
        }
        /*
        TODO: make this work for ifstream, fstream, and FILE* file objects.
        ex.
            std::fstream fileobj(".\example.file", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
            AraHaan::hexstream hexstrm;
            hexstrm << fileobj; //<  itterates through the file object and hex arrays the data in it.
        */
        void operator<< (void* cool) {}
        void operator<< (int character) {
            // Note: Clearing the hexstream after every character is the user's responsibility
            //     if ran in a for loop that can dublicate the information that is if the data from
            //     the hexstream is obtained and added to a string after every itteration.
            AddCharacter(character);
        }
        basic_hexstream() {}
        ~basic_hexstream() {
            // clears the data just in case.
            // This makes clearing this manually optional.
            if(!data_cleared) {
                clear();
            }
        }
    };
}

#endif
```

But yeah, I need to implement the operator<< properly for this in the `basic_hexstream` class for this to work right somehow on not only file objects but also when someone passes in a character that was casted to an `int`.
How can I use the operator<< for feeding an file object to the `hexstream` class using << like shown in the example above and also fulfill all the things that I need it to do?

Comment: "I need an overload of operator<< that can let me do something like this:"  You almost certainly don't need to do that. You could simply use a named function to do whatever it is you want, which isn't clear. You only need to overload operator << if you want to integrate it with the other iostream facilities, which apparently you don't, as your hexstream class has no relationship with them.

Comment: What I am wanting is not only an ``operator<<`` for passing the int character to the hexstream without explicitly calling ``AddCharacter`` and a version for passing the file object that does the itteration of the file before passing every character which would be casted to ``int`` to ``AddCharacter``. Basically long story short I want for it to be able to do all of the file itteration stuff for when people want to hex array an entire file's contents (which would be needed for things like hex editors). So basically so way it can sorten people's code as much as possible and yet do the same thing

Comment: Something appears to be missing from this question. That would be an actual question. The only thing that's stated here is what you need. That's not a question. You need to edit what you've written here, and add a specific, concise question. A long-winded novel, consisting of "I need this, and I need that", is off-topic for stackoverflow.com

Comment: So the basic idea here is to have a stringstream that everything written to it is encoded in hexadecimal? So (for example) if I did `somehexstream << "1234";` I'd get `31323334` (or `0x310x320x330x341`)?

Comment: Yeah it would be something exactly like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use one of these approaches. Below, you have 2 examples of simple streams that takes the data from an `fstream` and outputs it in the console.

Example 1 (operator<< member function)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class TextStream
{
public:
    string getText() const;
    TextStream& operator<<(fstream& stream);

private:
    string text;
};

string TextStream::getText() const
{
    return text;
}

TextStream& TextStream::operator<<(fstream& stream)
{
    while (true)
    {
        string line;
        if (!std::getline(stream, line)) break;
        line += '\n';
        text += line;
    }

    return *this;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    fstream file1("temp1.txt");
    fstream file2("temp2.txt");

    TextStream ts;
    ts << file1 << file2;
    cout << ts.getText() << endl;

    file1.close();
    file2.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Example 2 (operator<< friend function)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class TextStream
{
public:
    string getText() const;
    void append(const string& s);

    friend TextStream& operator<<(TextStream& textStream, fstream& fileStream);

private:
    string text;
};

string TextStream::getText() const
{
    return text;
}

void TextStream::append(const string& s)
{
    text += s;
}

TextStream& operator<<(TextStream& textStream, fstream& fileStream)
{
    while (true)
    {
        string line;
        if (!std::getline(fileStream, line)) break;
        line += '\n';
        textStream.append(line);
    }

    return textStream;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    fstream file1("temp1.txt");
    fstream file2("temp2.txt");

    TextStream ts;
    ts << file1 << file2;
    cout << ts.getText() << endl;

    file1.close();
    file2.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that help out a lot. Thanks

Comment: Ok, after all of that. This is a start of the new ``basic_hexstream`` class.
https://godbolt.org/g/YWSi5o

Answer (score 1):

If I were going to do this, I'd take a rather different approach.

Instead of writing the whole stream-like class, and having it be incompatible with existing streams, I'd write filtering `streambuf` class that converts data to hex on the way through:

```
class hex_buf : public std::streambuf {
    std::streambuf *buffer;
    bool use_prefix;
public:
    typedef std::char_traits<char> traits_type;
    typedef traits_type::int_type  int_type;

    hex_buf(std::ostream &os, bool use_prefix) : buffer(os.rdbuf()), use_prefix(use_prefix) {}

    int_type overflow(int_type c) {
        static const char chars[] = "0123456789abcdef";

        if (use_prefix) {
            buffer->sputc('0');
            buffer->sputc('x');
        }
        unsigned char ch = (unsigned char)c;
        buffer->sputc(chars[ch >> 4]);
        return buffer->sputc(chars[ch & 0xf]);
    }
};
```

We can then create a stream class that attaches to an existing stream, but adds that filtering streambuf to the mix:

```
class hex_stream : public std::ostream { 
    hex_buf output;
public:   
    hex_stream(std::ostream &os, bool use_prefix = false) : output(os, use_prefix), std::ostream(&output) {}
};
```

Right now, I've written `hex_stream` to take an existing `ostream` as its destination. If you prefer, it's trivial to have it construct an ostream itself (e.g., you pass it a name, and it constructs an `fstream`, or you don't pass anything, and it constructs a stringstream).

To use this, we don't (normally) use the `hex_buf` class directly--we just use a hex_stream, and attach it to some existing stream:

```
    hex_stream s(std::cout);  
    s << "1234";

    hex_stream t(std::cout, true);  
    t << "1234";
```

With this, copying some other stream to this type of stream can be done the same way as we'd do it with any other stream:

```
hex_stream h(std::cout);   
std::ifstream infile("test.txt");

h << infile.rdbuf();
```

As to why you'd want to do things this way:

1. The code is actually shorter and simpler.
2. The result is a real ostream, so essentially everything that works with existing ostreams also works with it. For example, consider the myriad existing stream insertion operators. For example, something like this:

   ```
   struct foo {
       int a;
       bool b;

       friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, foo const &f) {
           return os << std::boolalpha << f.a << ", " << f.b;
       }
   };
   ```

This works just fine with a `hex_stream` as it's defined here:

```
hex_stream ss(std::cout, true);

foo f{ 1, false };

ss << f;
```

Produces the output: `0x310x2c0x200x660x610x6c0x730x65`

In this case, the 0x31 is the `1`, 0x2c is the comma, 0x20 is the space, and `0x660x610x6c0x730x65` is the ISO-8859 encoding of `false`, expressed in hexadecimal.

In other words, not only the existing stream insertion operators, but a user-provided overloaded insertion operator will work--and so (as we show with `std::boolalpha`) do existing stream manipulators.

There is an alternative way to do this that might qualify as even more correct. Instead of creating a filtering stream buffer, you could create a `codecvt` facet that encodes output as hexadecimal. This is already a pretty long post, so I'll refrain from including code for that right now.